# How to select a Tab in my TabbedViewNavigator?

Tags: apache-flex, select, mobile, swipe, tabbar

i gave my mobile app two ways to navigate, on the one hand the way so swipe (left/right) and on the other hand the normal tabbar at the bottom to "point" with your finger. So, as I added the swipe function I recognized that the bar wont update their buttons as I swipe to another page - Im looking for some commands that select the specific button of my swipped tab.

```
init():
        protected function init():void{
            this.addEventListener( TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, handleSwipe );  
        }



handleSwipe():

        private function handleSwipe(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
        {
            var slideViewTransition:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();    
            // Swipe was to the right
            if (event.offsetX == 1 ) {
                slideViewTransition.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.RIGHT;
                navigator.pushView( views.HomeView, null, null, slideViewTransition );
                play("swipeee");
            }
                // Swipe was to the left
            else if (event.offsetX == -1 ) {
                slideViewTransition.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.LEFT;
                navigator.pushView( views.HomeView, null, null, slideViewTransition );
                play("swipeee");
            }
        }
```

I guess I have to get the data from my tabbedViewNavigator MainClass... but I have no idead how